# Error in finding shortest path of a graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra

I have written code to output the shortest path between two nodes 
**Input Format**-First line contain two numbers ,indicating **nodes** and **edges** ,
 second line contains 2 numbers among which shortest path has to be calculated and then number of edges lines follows

My code is taking input more than the number of edges

e.g-

> 7 9
>   0 6
>   0 1 1
>   0 2 1
>   0 3 2
>   0 4 3
>   1 5 2
>   2 6 4
>   3 6 2
>   4 6 4
>   5 6 1
>   Code is taking 13 inputs and I am unable to find the bug

**Code**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<vector> 
#include<queue>
typedef pair <long long int ,long long int> p;
vector<p> adj[100000];
vector<int> ver[100000];
void dijkstra(long long int x,long long int b);
int main()
  {
  long long nodes,t,edges,x,y,weight,a,b;
    cin>>nodes>>edges;
    cin>>a>>b;
    for(long long int i=1;i<=edges;i++)
      {
      cin>>x>>y>>weight;    
      adj[x].push_back(make_pair(weight,y));
      } 
    dijkstra(a,b);
  return 0;
}

void dijkstra(long long int a,long long int b)
  {
  priority_queue< p,vector<p>,greater <p> > q;
  long long int cost[100000];
  memset(cost,1000000,sizeof(cost));
  q.push(make_pair(0,a));
  cost[a]=0;
  while(!q.empty())
   {
      p pi=q.top();  
      q.pop();
     long long int u=pi.second;   //vertex
      long long int v=pi.first;    //weight
      if(cost[u]<v)  
      continue;      
      for(long long int i=0;i<adj[u].size();i++)
      {
       long long int w=adj[u][i].first;   //edge weight
       long long int x=adj[u][i].second; //vertex

        if(cost[x]>cost[u]+w)
          {
              ver[u].clear();
              ver[u].push_back(x);//prevcost[x]=cost[x];    
              cost[x]=cost[u]+w;
              q.push(p(cost[x],x)); 

          }
          if(cost[x]=cost[u]+w)
          ver[u].push_back(x);
      }
    }

  for(long long int i=0;i<ver[b].size();i++)
  cout<<ver[b][i]<<"->";
  cout<<"\n";
 }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

this is stripped down version of your code that takes only the input from terminal. Do not store value in vector or call dijkstra function. 
It takes input for only 9 edges as desired....

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
//typedef pair <long long int ,long long int> p;
///vector<p> adj[100000];
//vector<int> ver[100000];
//void dijkstra(long long int x,long long int b);
using namespace std;
int main()
  {
    long long nodes,t,edges,x,y,weight,a,b;
    cin>>nodes>>edges;
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<"nodes "<<nodes<<"edges "<<edges<<endl;
    for(long long int i=1;i<=edges;i++)
      {
      cin>>x>>y>>weight;

      //adj[x].push_back(make_pair(weight,y));
      }
    //dijkstra(a,b);
  return 0;
}
```

Please check the way you are entering data through the terminal.